# Flexible if condition in c#

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have 7 checkboxes and i have 7 variables. (cbxA, cbxB.... cbxG and iA,iB...iG). And i want to to this:

```
List<int> iList=new List<int>();
for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
   if (cbxA.Checked && cbxB.Checked) 
   {
      if (i<iA && i<iB)
      {
          iList.Add(i);
      }  
   }
   //. . . i want to do like that. 
}
```

How can i do that? Thank you in advance.

Edit: I try to explain what i want to do. Here is:
I want to create flexible if programmaticaly. For example:

if cbxB and cbxC and cbxE checked then my if condition should be like below:

```
   if (i<iB && i<iC && i<iE)
   {
       iList.Add(i);
   }
```

if cbxA and cbxB checked then my if condition should be like below:

```
  if (i<iA && i<iB)
  {
      iList.Add(i);
  }
```

if cbxD and cbxE and cbxG checked then my if condition should be like below:

```
  if (i<iD && i<iE && i<iG)
  {
      iList.Add(i);
  }
```

And something like that. I hope this is clear.

Comment: I think you need to clarify the question - I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: **C**hecked, **A**dd... try to be accurate when posting/presenting existing code.

Comment: You have `N` checkboxes, representing `N` conditions and you want to check only those conditions who's checkboxes are checked. When `i` satisfies all active conditions, add it to the list. Did I understand the question correctly?

Comment: grek40 yes you are right.

Comment: thank you but no it isn't a solution.

Comment: `if (!cbxA.Checked || (cbxA.Checked && i<iA)) && (!cbxB.Checked || (cbxB.Checked && i<iB)) &&(....)) { iList.Add(i); }`

Comment: Sten thank you wooow it seems that this is an incredible solution. I'll try it and write again ASAP. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
    Dictionary<int, int> _map = new Dictionary<int, int>()
    {
        /*{ cbxA, iA },*/
        /*{ cbxB, iB }*/
        /*...*/
    };

    public List<int> GetCheckboxFilteredNumbersUpTo100()
    {
        //find lowest border of all checkboxes, and cut tail of 100 by it.
        var min = _map.Where(x => x.Key.Checked).Select(x => x.Value).DefaultIfEmpty(100).Min();
        return Enumerable.Range(0, Math.Min(min,100)).ToList();
    }
```

Just fill map with your checkboxes and their corresponding min-indexes.

Comment: You don't need dictionary here (btw, it's `Dictionary<ComboBox, int>` type), plain `List<Tuple<Dictionary,int>>` is ok (though using `Item1` and `Item2` is *kek* I agree, custom type `Item` and `List<Item>` may solve that). And you really have to explain the logic (it's very well obscured, you barely need any obfuscator now) ;)

Comment: Well, yes. I agree, but if you have complex logic - you better name it properly. Cause in fact what OP asked is very simple. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer eocron but i don't understand your solution. maybe i can solve this problem via dlinq but i don't want to use DLINQ.

Comment: A dictionary when just an if statement would suffice is quite wasteful. And it's harder to read on top of that

Comment: Well, this is pretty much "holy war" statement. We are on stackoverflow, so you are free to present your own answer instead of downvoting correct answer which you dislike.

Answer (score 0):

You can group the two if statements together and check that either the box is unchecked or that `i` is less than the variable. So it would look like

```
if (cbxA.checked || cbxB.checked || ...)
{
    if ((!cbxA.checked || i < iA) && (!cbxB.checked || i < iB)...)
    {
        iList.add(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: WereGoingOcean thank you for your answer but it is not a solution. i've just edited my post. Please check it.